# Flash Player event bubbling/capturing mode

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

Can someone please give a simple example of where we could use capture mode rather than bubbling mode for a Flash Player event?

Most of the time we are using bubbling mode and we set `useCapture` to false (when adding an event listner). What would be the ideal situation to use the capturing phase?

Answer (score 2):

Basically if you want to stop propagation, you should use the capturing phase. For example, you have a default keyboard listener, and you want to cancel that in a rare condition. There are some points when you may want to use the capturing phase, but those can be achieved without it. To understand capturing and bubbling phase, see image below:

[image]

Comment: @TrexTroy it's also useful if you want a parent object to listen for the same event from multiple child objects. You could do that with a bubbling event, but as you can imagine, the capture phase lets you handle the event a lot earlier in the process.